# aggregate of list inside list in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I added list something like below on spring `Model`

```
model.addAttribute("myObjList", myObjList);
```

where `myObjList` is list of `MyObject` class

```
List<MyObject> myObjList;
```

And `MyObject` class is something like below

```
public class MyObject{

private List Account;
//getter setter
}
```

and `Account` class is as

```
public class Account{

private double amount
//other properties
//getter setter
}
```

now i need to use tymeleaf `#aggregate` to find sum of `amount` but could not figure out how can i do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a total sum of all accounts:

```
${#aggregates.sum(myObjList.![#aggregates.sum(accounts.![amount])])}
```

[Collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection) allows you to generate a list from another property.  Becuase you have two lists (myObjList and accounts), you have to use it twice.

The inner projection (`#aggregates.sum(accounts.![amount])`) gives you a sum all accounts for a `MyObject`.  The outer projection sums everything together for all the `myObjList` (`#aggregates.sum(myObjList.![...])`).

Comment: You are so wonderful. It is working like a charm but could you explain few lines behind how this is working so i would have more idea.

Comment: I added what I could and a link to the documentation.