# I want to do variable calculation with thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to calculate the total cost of items using the given information in HTML.

```
<div class="wrap" th:with="tot=0">
```

.......

```
<li class="p-list" th:each="dto:${list}">
    <p class="p-sprice" th:text="|${dto.price}|"></p>
    <p class="p-count" th:text="|${dto.count}|"></p>
    <th:block th:with="tot=${tot}+${dto.count}*${dto.price}"></th:block>
</li>
```

The code above is my attempt, but it is obviously incorrect!

Comment: th:with variables aren't real variables.  You cannot reassign them, or add to them and they only apply in the child tags of them.  If you wish to sum a table, but not do it in Java, I would suggest learning about collection aggregrates like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241132/aggregate-of-list-inside-list-in-thymeleaf/56241526#56241526

Answer (score 0):

It will be a lot easier to calculate the total in Java code and add an extra attribute in your controller code.

For example:

```
@GetMapping
public String showList(Model model) {
  // get list from somewhere first

  model.addAttribute("list", list);

  model.addAttribute("total", calculateTotal(list));
}

// Have some private method to calculate the total below
```

Then just use the `total` attribute in your Thymeleaf template.